# Control + V not working using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, keyboard-events

I am trying to copy and paste a object, keyboard action using selenium c#, it works for Ctrl+c but not Ctrl + v.

sample script below:
`Action copyAction = GetActions();
Action pasteAction = GetActions();
copyAction.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "c").Build().Perform();

Now click a folder to paste above copied object
Thread.Sleep(1000);
pasteAction.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v").Build().Perform();`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: using mouse you can paste ?

Comment: no i am afraid its just a key board action

Comment: I would use Windows.Forms' SendKeys instead. Reference:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me! It allows me to use it with Sendkeys

```
Clipboard.SetText(target);
PageObjects.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.KeyDown(Keys.Control);

    action.SendKeys("v");

    action.KeyUp(Keys.Control);

    action.Build().Perform();
```

KeyDown(): This method simulates a keyboard action when a specific keyboard key needs to press.

KeyUp(): The keyboard key which presses using the KeyDown() method, doesn’t get released automatically, so keyUp() method is used to release the key explicitly.

SendKeys(): This method sends a series of keystrokes to a given web element.